MS Outlook - Error: "Customized functionality in this application will not work because the certificate"
I have managed to sell my first unit of my Outlook COM add-in (written in C#). But when my customer tries to install my add-in, he gets an error message in the installation process: "Custom functionality in this application will not work because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for FolderSearch or its location is not trusted".
Does anyone know what to do? ChatGPT tells me to buy a certificate. But where can I get one? And how can I use it to sign my add-in?
Thank you and best regards.

https://www.google.com/search?q=buy+code+signing+certificate
